# Python version 2.7 does not allow duplicate * expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

Look this example:
I have two tuples of coordinates: `coor_a`, `coor_b`, which is generated from `numpy.which`. And it's structure like this: `coor_a = ([ya1, ya2, ... yan], [xa1, xa2, ... xan])`
If I want process this two coordinates concurrently, I would like to use this way in python3:

```
for ya, xa, yb, xb in zip(*coor_a, *coor_b):
    ...
```

But in python2, it's a SyntaxError. And Pycharm will warning: `python version 2.7 does not duplicate * expression`. Of course I can replace `zip(*coor_a, *coor_b)` with `zip(coor_a[0], coor_a[1], coor_b[0], coor_b[1])`, but it's not elegant! So I'm expecting a more simple and convenient way to implement it.

Thank for any reply!

Comment: If you don't mind increasing memory consumption, `zip(*(ca + cb))` is always an option but not recommended.

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks a lot. Could you recommend more appropriate way? Don't need to rigidly adhere to my way. Just implement the same function.

Comment: The issue is that Python 2 prohibits a lot of these "elegant" syntax. Even with the usage of `zip` is bad in terms of memory consumption cost as it fully generates the list in Python 2, while in Python 3 it would actually be a memory efficient iterator.  In Python 2 you would have to use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) while this isn't available under Python 3.  With the deprecation of Python 2 completely looming over the horizon it really isn't worth supporting Python 2 for new code going forward.

Comment: Basically, there is no possible solution that is efficient for both Python 2 and 3 at the same time, and that there is no possible solution that make use of the "elegant" syntax that work under both Python 2 and 3 without resulting in significant increase in memory consumption under both 2 and 3.

Comment: @metatoaster Ok, thank you very much! I've got it. I need migrate my algorithms to ros, so I have to use python2. Anyway, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is natural that newer software versions provide additional features.

Try:

```
for ya, xa, yb, xb in zip(*(coor_a + coor_b)):
    ...
```